# Compiling D2RQ with ant

Tags: java, ant, d2rq

[D2RQ](http://www.d2rq.org) is shipped with an `ant` build script, which works fine.  I can compile on a linux box, where the default ant version is 1.8.2 and the javac version is 1.7.0_121.

I want to compile D2RQ with Java 8. I've downloaded ant 1.10, which requires Java 8 <sup>[2](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#java-version)</sup>.

Then I run into some issues:

- When I run ant 1.10 without changing the source (or target) option, ant seems to run successfully - even though the default version of java on the system is 1.7 (i.e. <8) - I would have expected it to complain it didn't have a valid version of java?
- I've tried modifying the `compile` target in the build.xml file from

  ```
  source="1.5"
  target="1.5"
  ```

  to

  ```
  source="1.8"
  target="1.8"
  ```

  but I get an error of:

  ```
  compile:
      [javac] Compiling 171 source files to /home/chris/d2rq/bldsrc
      [javac] javac: invalid target release: 1.8
  ```

  I get the same error if I replace '1.8' with just '8', but '1.6' and '1.7' both work.
- I then tried a different approach (after a bit more Googling) and replaced

  ```
  source="1.5"
  target="1.5"
  ```

  with

  ```
  fork="yes"
  executable="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-0.b15.el6_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java"
  ```

  the location of java 8 is valid, but running the compile task now results in

  ```
  compile:
      [javac] Compiling 171 source files to /home/chris/d2rq/bldsrc
      [javac] Unrecognized option: -d
      [javac] Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
      [javac] Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
  ```

I don't even know if `-d` is a D2RQ compile option or a valid java flag.

Is there anything else I should be trying?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `executable` attribute of `<javac>` must point to the `javac` executable, not `java`. Note the `"c"` at the end of `javac`.

The following must be changed to point to `javac`:

```
executable="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-0.b15.el6_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java"
```

Where `javac` lives depends on your Linux distribution.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it would be something simple! (Can you tell Java isn't my favoured language...)

Comment: Although, it still doesn't answer my question of why `target="1.8"` doesn't work, or why ant 1.10 doesn't complain about being run under Java 1.5

Comment: `target="1.8"` wouldn't work if version 1.7 or older of the `javac` executable was being used.

Comment: Ant 1.10 simply can't run under Java 1.5. It would fail with an error message like `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`. If that error isn't occurring, then an older version of Ant is being run.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realised that running `./ant` _still_ runs the system version of ant because it depends for `ANT_HOME`

Answer (score 1):

There is also [ONT-D2RQ](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-d2rq) with java8, jena3 and maven